Removing same requests in postman
I am having  few GET requests in my collection,repeating at many instances... For example, A GET request is used for a job creation validation, same call is used after job edit validation, and then job deletion.
I want to eliminate the repetitive GET Calls by keeping only one call than calling after it wherever required....
Is is possible in postman?
Need to call request by keeping one request wherever required

You might find Postman Variables helpful, you can set variables and environements giving you different configurations for those different use-cases. This way you can have a single request behave slightly different, however this only really works if only your values change and not the keys

I want to eliminate the repetitive GET Calls Okay, so remove them from your collection.  What is the difficulty?
